# How I can determine the latest version in URL?

Tags: scripting, version, url

I'm trying to put a "function" inside of a script to install the latest version of "TeamSpeak3" Client and make all configurations.

My problem is I don't know how to make a function to test the version number part, "*number*.*number*.*number*.*number*". The numbers range from 0 to 99.

For example, I'm given a variable that has the value within a URL:

```
URL=http://dl.4players.de/ts/releases/$version/TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_$arch-$version.run
```

Here the variable, $Version, the latest is 3.0.16. The current latest URL is:

```
http://dl.4players.de/ts/releases/3.0.16/TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_x86-3.0.16.run
```

But in the future when I use the script, I want it to determine automatically the latest version, checking the numbers within the URL.

For "archs" I have this code:

```
# Determining the system arch
arch=$(uname -m)
case "$arch" in
x86)    arch="x86"  ;;
i?86)   arch="x86"  ;;
amd64)  arch="amd64"    ;;
x86_64) arch="x86_64"   ;;
* ) echo "Your Arch '$arch' -> Its not supported."  ;;
esac
```

Maybe an array or something like that? Can someone help me with this idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what it is you're asking exactly. Assuming you mean you want to find the latest version listed in http://dl.4players.de/ts/releases/, you can do this:

```
curl -s http://dl.4players.de/ts/releases/ | \
  grep -Po '(?<=href=")[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+){2,3}(?=/")' | \
  sort -Vr | head -1
```

Example output:

```
3.0.16
```

Explanation:

- Note that the directory listing HTML follows a fairly *regular* pattern:

  ```
  <tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/folder.gif" alt="[DIR]"></td><td><a href="3.0.0/">3.0.0/</a></td><td align="right">10-Aug-2011 16:57  </td><td align="right">  - </td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
  <tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/folder.gif" alt="[DIR]"></td><td><a href="3.0.1/">3.0.1/</a></td><td align="right">17-Nov-2011 08:43  </td><td align="right">  - </td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
  ```

  All the version folder links are created with `href="X.Y.Z[.A]/"`, `A`, `X`, `Y` and `Z` all being numbers.
- So we can `grep` for this pattern: `(?<=href=")[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+){2,3}(?=/")`. I have used Perl regexes (`-P`) for [lookaheads and lookbehinds](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=518444) (so that the string is surrounded by `href="` and `/"`, but these two aren't part of the actual match). The regex `[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+){2,3}` means:

  1. One or more digits: `[0-9]+`, followed by,
  2. A group consisting of a period and one or more digits (`(\.[0-9]+)`), repeated two or three times (`{2,3}`).
- Then we do version `sort` and get the top result.

---

[Ordinarily, one should not use Regular expressions to parse HTML.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) However, I think on occasion an exception can be made.

Answer (score 2):

This is why you shouldn't use pure shell scripting. Instead, is better to use something that *is meant for the task*, like uscan (which is a perl script), instead of doing it yourself:

```
$ uscan --watchfile teamspeak --package TeamSpeak3 --no-download --verbose --upstream-version 3.0.16
-- In test, processing watchfile line:
   http://dl.4players.de/ts/releases/([\d\.]+)/TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_amd64-([\d\.]+).run
-- Found the following matching hrefs:
     TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_amd64-3.0.16.run (3.0.16)
Newest version on remote site is 3.0.16, local version is 3.0.16
 => Package is up to date
```

the content of the teamspeak file is:

```
version=2
http://dl.4players.de/ts/releases/([\d\.]+)/TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_amd64-([\d\.]+).run
```

In the example above, I am manually setting the version of the latest version, if you want to, you can replace the version from TeamSpeak if they support the `--version` parameter, ie.:

```
$ uscan --watchfile teamspeak --package TeamSpeak3 --no-download --verbose --upstream-version $(teamspeak --version)
```

it should output a numeric value. It also possible to automagically download the latest run file, just remove the `--no-download` option. This has the advantage that it's very, very flexible, you don't need to modify anything when a new version goes out, nor worry about it breaking.

The only real limitation for your use case is that uscan doesn't support setting architectures, but such limitation is trivially overcome if you just create another file, say teamspeak-i386, and tweak the url like this:

```
version=2
http://dl.4players.de/ts/releases/([\d\.]+)/TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_x86-([\d\.]+).run
```

Comment: Is there a link to the uscan Perl script?

Comment: @slm http://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/collab-maint/devscripts.git/plain/scripts/uscan.pl

Answer (score 0):

I'd take the URLs and parse the version number from it:

```
$ echo 'http://dl.4players.de/ts/releases/3.0.16/TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_x86-3.0.16.run' \
    | awk -F'_x86-' '{print $2}' | sed 's/.run//'
3.0.16
```

With the version parsed out you can then use `sort` to determine which version is newer. Specifically with `sort`, using its `-V` switch, which newer versions have.

```
$ echo -e '3.0.16\n4.0.2\n1.2.3\n5.6.7\n3.0.17' | sort -V | tail -1
5.6.7
```

This is just a rough approach, but should show you how you can easily achieve what you're looking for.

**NOTE:** My `sort` version.

```
$ sort --version
sort (GNU coreutils) 8.21
```

Answer (score 0):

well with curl i can solve the Quake2 Lastest Version

```
Q2VA=$(curl -s http://deponie.yamagi.org/quake2/ | grep -Po "quake2-[0-9].[0-9][0-9].tar.xz" | sort -Vr | head -1)
```

But right now i am trying with LibreOffice, using the follow command :

```
curl -s http://www.libreoffice.org/download/download/ | grep -Po "[0-9].[0-9].[0-9]" | sort -Vr
```

Output :

```
93276
90701
89681
72663
50227
43905
42382
42382
26302
25220
20474
18000
14907
14764
14001
13964
13903
13902
13898
13890
13884
12887
12774
07992
700,9
100,3
6/5.4
6/5.3
5.4.0
5.4.0
5.4.0
5.4.0
5.4.0
5.4.0
5.4.0
5.4.0
5.4.0
5.4.0
5.4.0
5.4.0
5.4.0
5.4.0
5.4.0
5.4.0
5.4.0
5.4.0
5.4.0
5.4.0
5.4.0
5.4.0
5.4.0
5.4.0
5.4.0
5.4.0
5.4.0
5.4.0
5.4.0
5.4.0
5.4.0
5.4.0
5.4.0
5.4.0
5.4.0
5.4.0
5.4.0
5.4.0
5.4.0
5.4.0
5.4.0
5.4.0
5.4.0
5.4.0
5.4.0
5.4.0
5.4.0
5.4.0
5.4.0
5.4.0
5.4.0
5.4.0
5.4.0
5.4.0
5.4.0
5.4.0
5.4.0
5.4.0
5.4.0
5.4.0
5.4.0
5.4.0
5.4.0
5.4.0
5.4.0
5.4.0
5.4.0
5.4.0
5.4.0
5.4.0
5.4.0
5.4.0
5.4.0
5.4.0
5.4.0
5.4.0
5.4.0
5.4.0
5.4.0
5.4.0
5.4.0
5.3.5
5.3.5
5.3.5
5.3.5
5.3.5
5.3.5
5.3.5
5.3.5
5.3.5
5.3.5
5.3.5
5.3.5
5.3.5
5.3.5
5.3.5
5.3.5
5.3.5
5.3.5
5.3.5
5.3.5
5.3.5
5.3.5
5.3.5
5.3.5
5.3.4
5.3.4
5.2.7
5.2.7
2.6.2
1.1.0
0,400
0,300
0A500
0A500
```

How i can indicate just the first vale type "Number.Number.Number" for store in a variable ? in this case 5.4.0 the first, in the row 29, but if i use some like sed, this can change in the future, is not secure ever the row 29 ever had the lastest version.

Desire Output:

```
5.4.0
```

Someone can give some idea to solve it ?